# Why doesn't the strlen variable in a for loop get a data type?

Tags: c, for-loop, strlen

I found out about that little trick to make ***this*** more long-form code (not the i < strlen)...

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++)
{
    printf("%c", string1[i]);
}
```

... into ***this*** more short-hand code (note the n variable):

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(string1); i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%c", string1[i]);
}
```

my question is, why is NOT "**size_t** n = strlen(string1)"? Why do you not give n a data type?

Thankyou!

Comment: You have given `n` a datatype, it's an `int`.

Comment: Of course! I see what's going on. It's no different than saying "int a, b, c" etc. I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: The result of calling  a (non void) function is an *expression*. So, the comparison reduces to `i < expression` BTW: an expression has a type, too.

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t`. Converting the result to `int` is not a good idea.

Comment: Better to use `for (size_t i = 0; string1[i]; i++)` which stops at the _null character_.